# How to mock BLoC in Integration Test

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, mocking, integration-testing, bloc

I have a Flutter app that uses the `bloc` and `flutter_bloc` packages. I am trying to write an integration test using `flutter_driver` and `mockito`. How do I mock the `BlocProvider` and its children to always emit a single mocked state?

The original bloc:

```dart
class SummaryBloc extends Bloc<BlocEvent, BlocState> {
  final SummaryRepository repository;

  SummaryBloc(this.repository);

  @override
  BlocState<Summary> get initialState => BlocStateEmpty<Summary>();

  @override
  Stream<BlocState> mapEventToState(
    BlocEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is Fetch) yield BlocStateSuccess<Summary>(repository.getSummary());
  }
}
```

I have tried mocking the bloc and overriding the `state` getter:

```dart
class MockSummaryBloc extends Mock implements SummaryBloc {}
```

Then using mockito in the instrumented app:

```dart
final MockSummaryBloc summaryBloc = MockSummaryBloc();

// whenever the state stream getter is called, return the mocked stream.
when(summaryBloc.state).thenAnswer((_) async* {
    yield BlocStateSuccess<Summary>(mockSummary);
  });
```

For good measure I have tried the same for `initialState`.

To use the mock in the instrumented app, I use `BlocProvider.value`:

```dart
runApp(BlocProvider.value(
    value: summaryBloc,
    child: MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test Driver',
      home: Scaffold(
          body: BlocBuilder(
        bloc: summaryBloc,
        // the builder rebuilds on state change.
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Text('state: ${state?.runtimeType ?? 'isNull'}');
        },
      )),
    ),
  ));
```

I expect the Text widget to print `BlocStateSuccess<Summary>` during runtime. However, the state is null during the lifespan of the driver test.

Am I incorrectly mocking this Bloc? Are there other methods of mocking a Bloc, or `Stream<BlocState>`?

Comment: Can you provide the definition of the SummaryBloc class ?

Comment: Thank you, I have added it. The SummaryRepository implementation shouldn't be necessary, so I've left it out.

Comment: Thanks. And what's the definition of `MockSummaryBloc` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to mock `SummaryRepository` instead of the Bloc. That will allow you to test the behavior of the bloc and keeping control of what the repository returns to the stream.

```
class MockSummaryRepository extends Mock implements SummaryRepository{}

var mockRepository = MockSummaryRepository();
when(mockRepository.getSummary()).thenReturn(mockSummary);

final SummaryBloc summaryBloc = SummaryBloc(mockRepository);
```